# Ruby on rails: Issue with one to one database insertion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables (i.e. users and profiles). The schema of the tables is:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "username"
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
end

create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "gender"
  t.integer  "birth_year"
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

The model is:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todo_lists
  has_many :many_items, through: :todo_lists, source: :todo_items
end
```

I am trying to add the records through following steps:

```
user = User.create! username: "Fiorina",password_digest: "abc"
user_profile = Profile.create! gender:"F",birth_year:"1954",first_name:"Carly",last_name:"Fiorina"
user_profile.profile = user
```

However I get the error:

"NoMethodError: undefined method `profile=' for #"

The error message is clear.However, I do not know how resolve it, i.e. how to create `profile` method. Also, I am reading the below blog and it says a one to one relationship will create 4 method. Is there anyway to ensure that 4 methods were created.

http://requiremind.com/differences-between-has-one-and-belongs-to-in-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `user` of `user_profile`

`user_profile.user=user`

But there is a shorter way to do the same thing

`user.create_profile(gender:"F",birth_year:"1954",first_name:"Carly",last_name:"Fiorina")`

This will automatically create the profile for this user.

You can also use `build_profile` if don't wanna save it at this point

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :todo_lists
  has_many :many_items, through: :todo_lists, source: :todo_items
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change it to:

```
user_profile.user = user
```

according your database field and association name.